# Seeking clarification and recommendations on unexpected patterns in Postgresql index usage statistics

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I am trying to prune unused and rarely used indexes based on the following stats:

- `pg_stat_user_indexes.idx_scan`: *[Number of index scans initiated on this index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW)*
- `pg_stat_user_indexes.idx_tup_read`: *[Number of index entries returned by scans on this index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW)*
- `pg_stat_user_indexes.idx_tup_fetch`: *[Number of live table rows fetched by simple index scans using this index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW)*
- `pg_statio_user_indexes.idx_blks_read`: *[Number of disk blocks read from this index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STATIO-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW)*
- `pg_statio_user_indexes.idx_blks_hit`: *[Number of buffer hits in this index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STATIO-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW)*

I am using the query below to analyze the index usage and find the results curious.

The table shows the different usage patterns.  Some are expected, but others are not.

Can anyone answer the question posed for each unexpected pattern?

Based on those answers please provide a recommendation on if indexes that display those patterns should be dropped or kept.

*Note that the indexes were dropped and recreated and the application ran for two weeks before pulling the stats.*

| Expected? | Question | Has Scans | Has Tuples Read | Has Tuples Fetched | Has Blocks Hit | Has Blocks Fetched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | Why are there blocks hit but not fetched and not scanned? | false | false | false | true | false |
| false | Why are there blocks hit and fetched but not scanned? | false | false | false | true | true |
| false | Why are there scans but not tuples read or fetched? | true | false | false | true | true |
| false | Why are there blocks hit but not fetched? | true | true | true | true | false |
| true | Drop | false | false | false | false | false |
| true | Keep | true | true | true | true | true |
| true | Keep | true | true | false | true | true |

```postgres
WITH "index_stats" AS (
  SELECT 
    "pg_indexes"."schemaname",
    "pg_indexes"."tablename",
    "pg_indexes"."indexname",
    pg_relation_size("pg_stat_user_indexes"."indexrelid") AS "size",
    "idx_tup_read" <> 0 OR "idx_tup_fetch"  <> 0  AS "Has Tuple Stats",
    "idx_blks_hit" <> 0 OR "idx_blks_read" <> 0 AS "Has IO Stats",
    "idx_scan" <> 0  AS "Has Scans",
    "idx_tup_read" <> 0 AS "Has Tuples Read",
    "idx_tup_fetch"  <> 0 AS "Has Tuples Fetched",
    "idx_blks_hit"  <> 0 AS "Has Blocks Hit",
    "idx_blks_read" <> 0   AS "Has Blocks Fetched",
    CASE WHEN "idx_scan" = 0 THEN 'idx_scan: N ' ELSE 'idx_scan: Y ' END ||
    CASE WHEN "idx_tup_read" = 0 THEN 'idx_tup_read: N ' ELSE 'idx_tup_read: Y ' END ||
    CASE WHEN "idx_tup_fetch" = 0 THEN 'idx_tup_fetch: N ' ELSE 'idx_tup_fetch: Y ' END ||
    CASE WHEN "idx_blks_hit" = 0 THEN 'idx_blks_hit: N ' ELSE 'idx_blks_read: Y ' END ||
    CASE WHEN "idx_blks_read" = 0 THEN 'idx_blks_read: N ' ELSE 'idx_blks_read: Y ' END AS "usage_status",
    "pg_stat_user_indexes"."idx_scan",   
    "pg_stat_user_indexes"."idx_tup_read",  
    "pg_stat_user_indexes"."idx_tup_fetch",
    "pg_statio_user_indexes"."idx_blks_hit",
    "pg_statio_user_indexes"."idx_blks_read",
    "pg_indexes"."indexdef"
  FROM 
    "pg_indexes"
  LEFT JOIN 
    "pg_stat_user_indexes" 
      ON 
        "indexrelname" = "indexname"
      AND 
        "pg_indexes"."schemaname" = "pg_stat_user_indexes"."schemaname"
  LEFT JOIN 
    "pg_statio_user_indexes"
      ON 
        "pg_statio_user_indexes"."indexrelname" = "pg_indexes"."indexname"
      AND
       "pg_statio_user_indexes"."schemaname" = "pg_indexes"."schemaname"),
  "stat_summary" AS (
  
SELECT
  "schemaname",
  "Has Scans",
  "Has Tuple Stats",
  "Has IO Stats",
  "Has Tuples Read",
  "Has Tuples Fetched",
  "Has Blocks Hit",
  "Has Blocks Fetched",
  COUNT(*) AS "stat_pattern_count",
  "usage_status"
FROM 
  "index_stats"
GROUP BY 
  "schemaname",
  "Has Tuple Stats",
  "Has IO Stats",
  "Has Scans",
  "Has Tuples Read",
  "Has Tuples Fetched",
  "Has Blocks Hit",
  "Has Blocks Fetched",
  "usage_status"
ORDER BY
  "schemaname", 
  "Has Scans" DESC,
  "Has Tuples Read" DESC,
  "Has Tuples Fetched" DESC,
  "Has Blocks Hit" DESC,
  "Has Blocks Fetched" DESC
)
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN "Has Scans" AND NOT "Has Tuple Stats" THEN 
      FALSE
    WHEN "Has Scans" AND "Has Blocks Hit" AND NOT "Has Blocks Fetched" THEN
      FALSE
    WHEN NOT "Has Scans" AND "Has IO Stats" THEN
      FALSE
    WHEN "Has Scans" AND "Has Tuple Stats" THEN
      TRUE
    WHEN NOT "Has Scans" AND NOT "Has IO Stats" THEN
       TRUE
    END AS "Expected?",
  "Has Scans",
  "Has Tuples Read",
  "Has Tuples Fetched",
  "Has Blocks Hit",
  "Has Blocks Fetched",
  CASE 
    WHEN "Has Scans" AND NOT "Has Tuple Stats" THEN 
      'Why are there scans but not tuples read or fetched?'
    WHEN "Has Scans" AND "Has Blocks Hit" AND NOT "Has Blocks Fetched" THEN
      'Why are there blocks hit but not fetched?'
    WHEN NOT "Has Scans" AND "Has Blocks Hit" AND "Has Blocks Fetched" THEN
      'Why are there blocks hit and fetched but not scanned?'
    WHEN NOT "Has Scans" AND "Has Blocks Hit" AND NOT "Has Blocks Fetched" THEN
      'Why are there blocks hit but not fetched and not scanned?'
    WHEN "Has Scans" AND "Has Tuple Stats" THEN
      'Keep'
    WHEN NOT "Has Scans" AND NOT "Has IO Stats" THEN
      'Drop'
    END AS "Question"
FROM 
  "stat_summary"
WHERE
  "schemaname"='my_schema'
ORDER BY 
  "Expected?", 
  "Has Scans",
  "Question" DESC
```

Comment: Too many questions in one, and the query is too complicated for me to dig through it and figure out if it is correct or not. I prefer [my own query](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) to find unnecessary indexes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe There are 4 related questions being asked:

1. What conditions cause blocks to be hit but not fetched, when an index is not scanned, & no tuples are read or fetched?

2. What conditions cause blocks to be hit & fetched when an index is not scanned, & no tuples are read or fetched?

3. What conditions cause an index to be scanned but no tuples are read or fetched?

4. Under what conditions are blocks hit but not fetched?

Are you recommending that I break these up into different posts?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that should be several different questions. Others might disagree.